# How to resolve ClassNotFoundException in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently migrated my project from Eclipse to Android Studio. Earlier everything was working perfectly, but recently when I started working on it again I am not able to launch the application. Its always showing me the same error. I haven't changed anything on application level, still getting the same result. Here is the log I am getting

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android, PID: 6977
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.android.MobApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.MobApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:601)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4919)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5721)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.MobApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:986)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:587)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4919) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5721) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.MobApplication
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

As I have recently switched my IDE I am facing problems to solve this one. I have also tried the other answers but still unable to solve this error. Kindly help me with this so I can proceed with my project. 
Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: yeah @YoannHercouet, Several times but didn't worked.

Comment: @SalmanKhan can you share your app gradle build file here?

Comment: @SalmanKhan just try reseting the sdk path and then clean the project.restart studio and then try.

Comment: @JagjitSingh tried that solution but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the [65k methods limit.](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) Try to use the solutions in the link.

---

**Edit:** For others who stumble this issue - @Salman Khan added `multiDexEnabled true` to the gradle file (as written in the link) and it solved the problem. It would be still better to read the whole article and follow the steps there.

Comment: If not, I will delete my answer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12292782)

Comment: I will write a full answer, if the path to resolve it is this.

Comment: @UrielFrankel Thanks for the answer, I am trying it.

Comment: @UrielFrankel I have seen that link but it's explaining the concept of MultiDex. Can you please explain me how to resolve this error.

Comment: The error might be caused by exceeding the 65K method count limit. You can check if this is the problem by setting the app minimum sdk to 21 and above.

Comment: Hey @UrielFrankel I just add "multiDexEnabled true" in my build.gradle file and it worked.

Comment: I am glad it helped. That means that the error caused by the multi dex problem. The solution you did is written it the link. You should read the article i added.

Comment: I have "`multiDexEnabled true`" already, but still class not found.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced lambda with anonymous class:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException happened in my android studio project in two classes – in both of them there was lambda expressions. After I replaced lambda with anonymous class – the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to edit from:

```
String id = MyClass.class.toString();
```

Into:

```
String id = MyClass.class.getName();
```

> Because `.toString()` returns something like "`class mypackage.MyClass`" (instead of "`mypackage.MyClass`").